# VBA: Find months words in range and replace it with the number

Tags: vba, excel, loops, date, format

Below the code. I am trying to reaplace all the months names with the corresponding number. For example January with 01.

The problem is that I have a string as a result while i would like to have date format.

```
Sub AccDec()

Dim SrchRng As Range, cel As Range

NumRows = Range("B13", Range("B13").End(xlDown)).Rows.Count

Set SrchRng = Range(Cells(1, 13), Cells(NumRows, 15))
For Each cel In SrchRng
    If InStr(1, cel.Value, "January") > 0 Then
        cel.Offset(1, 0).Value = "/01/"
    End If
Next cel

End Sub
```

Any suggestion?

This is the result of the Macro. I would like to implement an if case.

Comment: What does the original string look like?  If you want a date object from it, it needs to be a parseable date string.

Comment: You need to provide more code. Where are you stuck? It's unclear.

Comment: Where is `SrchRng` meant to be looking at?  If `NumRows` is 5 then `SrchRng` will go from `M1` (row 1, column 13) to `O5` (row 5, column 15).  Is `January` just text or is it already a real date formatted to say just the month name?

Comment: Hello, the initial range is populated with strings like 14 July 2018, since they are taken from a word file; I am stuck at the point that instead of 14 January 2018 if I lunch the macro I get /01/ only; while I would like to 14/01/2018 as a date format

Comment: Hello, maybe I wasn't very clear. In the range selected there are text format content, Excel doesn't recognize dates; i don't think the solution is a format. I need to make the system recognize "14 July 2018" (for example) as 14/07/2018.

Answer (score 0):

I'll add this as an answer, but it depends what the current values in your cells are.

If `SrchRng` is looking at the correct cells and those cells contain just the word `January`, `February` or `Jan`, `Feb` then  you can use [DateValue](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/datevalue-function) to coerce that text into a real date.

Going from your last comment that the text is, for example, 14 July 2018:

```
cel = DateValue(cel)
cel.NumberFormat = "mm"
```

Use this code within the loop to convert the values to real dates displayed as a two digit month number.
The cell will contain the value `43295` which is 14th July in Excel speak (number of days since 1st Jan 1900).

The whole code would be:

```
Sub AccDec()

    Dim SrchRng As Range, cel As Range
    Dim NumRows As Long

    NumRows = Range("B13", Range("B13").End(xlDown)).Rows.Count

    Set SrchRng = Range(Cells(1, 13), Cells(NumRows, 15))

    MsgBox "Searching this range:  " & SrchRng.Address, vbOKOnly

    For Each cel In SrchRng
            cel = DateValue(cel)
            cel.NumberFormat = "mm"
    Next cel

End Sub
```

I've added the message box as I don't think it's looking at the correct range.  Also, if any cell doesn't have a value that can turn into a date it will error with a `Type Mismatch`.